# Gulp pipe minimal function?

Tags: node.js, gulp

What is smallest function that can be placed in a Gulp pipe and still work?

This doesn't work:

```
gulp.src('**')
  .pipe(function() {
    // what's the minimum that can go here and still be a functional pipe?
    // what needs to be returned? 
  });
```

Ideally this would be vanilla JS using only the foundational modules Gulp was built on; vinyl, through, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with your pipe is that you're dropping the files of your glob since you don't return them.

Using [through2](https://github.com/rvagg/through2), you can do something like this:

```js
const through = require('through2')

gulp.src('**')
  .pipe(through.obj((file, enc, cb) => cb(null, file)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I think my confusion was due to a misunderstanding of `.pipe()`, which expects a stream not a function.

Comment: @WhatIsHeDoing thanks for the edit! Although I prefer to link to the github repo, so I modified it :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's 4 years later, but I thought I'd throw in my solution to this since I was looking for the same answer.

I wanted some simple, modular `pipe` functions that I could reuse in a few different tasks, without excess dependencies. This might not be an elegant solution, but it works:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

var someFlag = true;

gulp.task('default', doTask);

function doTask(done) {
  let stream = gulp.src(['file.txt'])
  .pipe(/* some gulp plugin here */);

  if (someFlag) {
    stream = alterStream(stream);
  }

  return stream;
}

function alterStream(stream) {
  stream.pipe(/* another gulp plugin here */);
  return stream;
}
```

Instead of returning the stream first directly (`return gulp.src(...)`) I'm storing it in a variable, then altering it as needed with other pipes, and returning it last.